# Loop through a CSV, editing fields based on conditionals and expressions

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to import a CSV and loop through it, setting a new value to a field based on some math+conditionals. This is what I have so far:

```
import-csv "$folder\test2.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_.SubmissionID -ne "" -and $_.SubmissionID -ne "SubmissionID"){
    echo $_
    $totaldocs = $_.TotalDocs
    $addnpages = $_.AddnPages
    if ($_.SubmitterName -match "check|Check"){
    echo "YES"
    $_.Cost = ([int]$totaldocs * .09)
    }
    if ($_.SubmitterName -notmatch "check|Check"){
    echo "NO"
    $_.Cost = (([int]$totaldocs + [int]$addnpages) * .05)
    }
    echo $_.Cost
  }
} |
export-csv "$folder\test3.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Debugging this chunk I can see that the "Cost" field is being set, however, when it exports the final CSV, the changes do not stick. Not only that, but there are additional blank lines between each line.

Is there something I'm missing? I'm open to suggestions if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: without a few lines of the input CSV and the desired results for those lines, this is really quite difficult to diagnose. [*grin*] ///// as an aside, i would make two changes -- [1] `-match` is case insensitive, so `check` is all you need. -- [2] the 2nd IF is unneeded since the tests are for opposites of each other. use an `else` instead of the 2nd IF.

Comment: If you are editing "columns" and want the changes to show then _after_ all the changes are made you need to send `$_` down the pipe. Sending something like `$_.Cost` _by itself_ will muddy your output. I also echo the first comment about `if`s and `-match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input CSV file looks something like this:

```
"SubmissionID","SubmitterName","TotalDocs","AddnPages","Cost"
"abcdef", "Check", "12", "3", "5"
"ghijkl", "check", "10", "7", "25"
```

The code below will do what you ask for (if I understand the question correctly)

```
Import-Csv "$folder\test2.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.SubmissionID)) -and $_.SubmissionID -ne "SubmissionID"){
    $totaldocs = $_.TotalDocs
    $addnpages = $_.AddnPages
    if ($_.SubmitterName -match "check") {  # -match is case-insensitive
        $_.Cost = ([int]$totaldocs * .09)
    }
    else {
        $_.Cost = (([int]$totaldocs + [int]$addnpages) * .05)
    }
    ###############################################################
    # output the result. This is what you forgot in the original code
    ###############################################################
    $_
  }
} | Export-Csv "$folder\test3.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"SubmissionID","SubmitterName","TotalDocs","AddnPages","Cost"
"abcdef","Check","12","3","1.08"
"ghijkl","check","10","7","0.9"
```

**EDIT**

Good observation by LotPings:

The above code will SKIP the rows that do not pass the test:

```
if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.SubmissionID)) -and $_.SubmissionID -ne "SubmissionID")
```

If you want those lines to be included in the output file also, we move the (outputted) `$_` one step down. The code then becomes:

```
Import-Csv "$folder\test2.csv" | ForEach-Object {
  if (!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.SubmissionID)) -and $_.SubmissionID -ne "SubmissionID"){
    $totaldocs = $_.TotalDocs
    $addnpages = $_.AddnPages
    if ($_.SubmitterName -match "check") {  # -match is case-insensitive
        $_.Cost = ([int]$totaldocs * .09)
    }
    else {
        $_.Cost = (([int]$totaldocs + [int]$addnpages) * .05)
    }
  }
  ###############################################################
  # output the result, changed or not.
  ###############################################################
  $_
} | Export-Csv "$folder\test3.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you, Theo. Yes it looks like I did not quite understand piping commands correctly. Once I output the result everything worked as intended.

Comment: This will remove rows not matching the conditions from output. IIUR the edit shall just calculate cost, if true move the `$_` one `}` further down.